# Routing binding to slug

Tags: laravel, routes, model-binding

How can I bind a route to a slug? If I don't want to pass an ID through the URL, but instead something like /locations/my-store where my-store would replace the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use simple routes (Laravel 5):

```
Route::get('/location/{slug}', 'LocationController@index');
```

And then catch slug, like:

```
public function index($slug) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Laravel are you using? In 5+ I know you can modify the model binging in the RouteServiceProvider like so:

```
$router->bind('location', function($value){
    return Location::where('id', $value)->orWhere('slug', $value)->first();
});
```

Comment: I am using version 5.2